# Open a month picker with specific months on click of input box

Tags: reactjs

I want open a month picker in react on clicking of input box or a calendar icon same as react widget datepicker. Moreover I want to apply a logic wherein only future months should be clickable and previous months to be disabled. Please let me know how I can do this in react.

i have use react-widget calander but its by default in open state. i have used react-widget month picker but after clicking on a particular month, the dates also appear
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Komal. Please make sure to show the community what you have already tried.

Comment: yes of course, i have edited my question